# Mysql - Rows to Columns on date

Tags: mysql

I think I need a little help with this one... It is for a timeclock. Rows need to be converted to columns per day. Below is a sample table and the result that I am trying to get.

Additional problems to consider: 
- Sometimes people forget to clock out. 
- Sometimes people may clock in and out multiple times in the same day

Here is my table:
 Table A

```
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
| ID    | User_id   |   DateTime            | inorout |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
| 1     |   5       |   2014-07-10 12:50:00 |   1     |
| 2     |   5       |   2014-07-10 17:40:00 |   0     |
| 3     |   5       |   2014-07-11 01:40:00 |   1     |
| 4     |   5       |   2014-07-11 02:50:00 |   0     |
| 5     |   5       |   2014-07-12 03:20:00 |   1     |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------+---------+
```

1 stands for In, 0 stands for Out

This is the result I am trying to get: 
--Results for User_id 5

```
ID  In                      Out                     Hours worked 
1   2014-07-10 12:50:00     2014-07-10 17:55:00     5:05 
2   2014-07-11 01:40:00     2014-07-11 02:50:00     1:10 
3   2014-07-12 03:20:00     NULL                    NULL
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you need help with? You haven't showed any code.

Comment: My question is I have a table and I am trying to get that result. I haven't posted any code, because after a few hours I haven't made any progress.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, what is wrong with my question?

Comment: @scottpaterson have you taken a look at my post?

Comment: 0 is the logout.. 1 is the login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do the trick for what you are looking for... basically you want to use a pivot on the table but there is a way to accomplish this without actually doing a pivot!!  like this.....

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    Login, 
    Logout,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, Login, Logout) / 60 as 'Hours Worked'
FROM(
    SELECT id, 
        MAX(IF(inorout = 1, DateTime, NULL)) AS Login,
        MAX(IF(inorout = 0, DateTime, NULL)) AS Logout
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY DATE(DateTime)
) AS temp;
```

[SEE FIDDLE:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/700c2/1)
using the MAX() aggregate on the date is a way to simulate a pivot on your table to transpose two rows (the login and logout) into two columns. hope that helps! :)

**EDIT:**
 your data does not match the expected results... i.e
LOGIN 2014-07-10 12:50:00 and LOGOUT 2014-07-10 17:40:00.. the logout time for the 10th is not what you posted for expected results... however this query accomplishes what you want.